# MSBuild cannot find a reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm currently trying to figure out why MSBuild is not able to compile one of our unit test dlls. The problem is only occuring with this DLL and not with the other unit test projects.

This is the output I receive from TeamCity when the build fails:

```
[10:38:55]: NAnt output:
[10:38:55]: [exec]
[10:38:55]: [exec]
[10:38:55]: [exec] "C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\Robinson.sln" (default target) (1) ->
[10:38:55]: [exec] "C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj" (default target) (19) ->
[10:38:55]: [exec] (CoreCompile target) ->
[10:38:55]: [exec] Modules\SecurityModuleTests.cs(10,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Modules' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] Modules\SecurityModuleTests.cs(197,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SecurityModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] TranslateTests.cs(10,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Utils' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] IPETests.cs(8,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] Pages\BasePageTest.cs(6,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Utils' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] Pages\BasePageTest.cs(7,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Pages' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] ServiceAsmxTests.cs(9,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] ServiceAsmxTests.cs(10,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Utils' does not exist in the namespace 'TenForce.Execution.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] Pages\BasePageTest.cs(16,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'basepage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec] ServiceAsmxTests.cs(22,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Service' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Robinson\trunk\Projects\Robinson\TenForceExecutionTests\TenForceExecutionTests.csproj]
[10:38:55]: [exec]
[10:38:55]: [exec] 2075 Warning(s)
[10:38:55]: [exec] 10 Error(s)
[10:38:55]: [exec]
[10:38:55]: [exec] Time Elapsed 00:01:40.06
```

The project ***TenForceExecutionTests*** is a simply DLL that contains several UnitTests of the MBunit Framework. This project has a reference to ***TenForceExecution*** which is a web application project and another reference to ***TenForce.Execution.Test***, which is another DLL containing logic for both projects.

When we compile everything on the development machine, it works without problems and the compile occurs without errors. On the build agent however this seems to fail...

***INFO***

- Target Framework : .NET4
- OS : Windows XP 32bit
- Windows 7 SDK Installed

***EDIT***

Did a clean checkout, and Visual Studio is able to build the entire solution, msbuild however cannot.

***EDIT 2***

Checked the dependencies:

- There is a project dependency between the projects
- There is a solution dependecy between the projects

***EDIT 3***
When I remove the reference to the webApplication project, and replace it with a reference to the compiled DLL of that project, the errors dissapear and the project compiles fine with MSBuild.

***EDIT 4***
I've ran the entire build from msbuild through a LOG and took a look at the specific task for compiling the project that's giving problems:

```
  Task "Csc"
    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\ASP.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\BUL\bin\Debug\BUL.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\BULTest\bin\Debug\BULTest.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\DAL\bin\Debug\DAL.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\Framework\bin\Debug\Framework.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\Gallio.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\Iesi.Collections.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\LanguageResource\bin\Debug\LanguageResource.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\log4net.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\MbUnit.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\NHibernate.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\PresentationBridge\bin\Debug\PresentationBridge.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\PresentationBridgeTest\bin\Debug\PresentationBridgeTest.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\System.Data.SQLite.DLL /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\TenForce.Execution.Test\bin\Debug\TenForce.Execution.Test.dll /reference:D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\Documents\RobinsonSource\Projects\Robinson\ThirdPartyComponents\WatiN.Core.dll /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\TenForceExecutionTests.dll /target:library Modules\SecurityModuleTests.cs TestRunSetup.cs TranslateTests.cs WebBaseTest.cs MetaTests.cs IPETests.cs Pages\BasePageTest.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs ServiceAsmxTests.cs Settings.Designer.cs "D:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\AppData\Local\Temp\6\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
    Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

From what I can tell, the actuall WebApplication is ***NOT*** included in the reference list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be a known problem in MSBuild as more people have issues with this.
I still haven't received a valid reply from Microsoft regarding this, but the discussion was continued here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/msbuild/thread/434abf1a-30db-4b13-8062-13755898dd71

Comment: Has there been any update to this? I am having this issue now, and can circumvent with EDIT 3. (Not ideal)

Comment: I submitted a bug report here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770426/msbuild-cant-find-project-reference-in-same-solution-if-it-is-not-selected-to-build-in-configuration-ex-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-a-could-not-be-found#details

Comment: I have had it with MSBuild, it is the worst build system of all time, no other build system has given me so much headache and I've had the luxury of working on a couple. For anyone who reads this, stay away from MSBuild, if there is any other way for you to create your build, use that.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Truth. I have 20 years of experience with other build systems, and I've never had to fight with a build system so much. MSBuild is astoundingly shit.

Comment: Now turns up "the page you requested was removed." :(   ...also, Rami's link turns up "Microsoft Connect has been retired". Hooray for the internet I guess?

Comment: The URL not exists any more

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue today, ended that the project that could not be referenced had a different platform specified, *x86* where the other projects where *Any Platform*. To get around this, I had to set the parameter with */p:Platform="Mixed Platforms"*. You can see what VS uses by going to Configuration Manager and looking at the *Active Solution Platform* selected in the top right.

Comment: This does let me compile, but it's kinda weird that this works and what the resulting platform actually becomes is kind of unknown? Kudos for the parameter though.

Comment: Ah, configuration manager actually has an option with mixed platforms. Coolness, msbuild issues gone.

Answer (score 3):

I also found a similar reference issue when building an UWP appx package. There are a lot of error messages look like:

`App.xaml.cs(6,15): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

If opening the sln file with VS2017, it builds no problem.

I did two things to fix this issue:

1. I noticed that the original solution requires winSDK 10.0.18362, but on my build machine, I don't have it. If opening with VS2017, it asks me to re-target the SDK to an installed older version. I think the msbuild may not be able to do the re-target, so I just downloaded and installed the required winSDK 18362.
2. I added a "**/t:restore**" option to the msbuild command line, and run the msbuild twice:

```
    msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /t:restore
    msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"
```

For restore, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I came across it today, so thought I would offer feedback for anyone else.

I've encountered this a few times and found that changing the Target Framework from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to just .NET Framework 4 does the trick.

Comment: @user2609980 right click on the project and hit properties. Target Framework dropdown will be on the Application tab.

Comment: This fix worked for me today in VS2010 with .NET four and a pair of assemblies; one a library and the other a console app. The library could ref the NUnit assemblies fine, and console app could not. When I switched Target Framework under Properties/Application from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to .NET Framework 4 the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue (Build successfully in **Visual studio**, but fail by **MSBUILD**).

After tried different solutions mentioned in this questions but failed.

Fortunately finally I found adding **-tv:version** resolve the errors.

For my project, the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in my A.csproj is v4.0, so I used the command like `msbuild A.csproj -tv:4.0` then succeeded to compile the projects.

Below are the struct of my solution:

1. Project A: startup project and target framework version=v4.0
2. Project B: reference project, its target framework version=v3.5
3. Project C: reference project, its target framework version=v3.5

It seems if not telling the specific target framework version to **MSBUILD** when exists multiple versions, sometimes it will get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a clean checkout to a new folder on your machine does it work over there too?

Most times these problems occur because you have a reference to something that is available locally but not in source control. This is a good check to see if everything that is needed for building your project is correctly referenced and under source control.

Comment: It has been working fine for nearly 10 years now, only when we started converting all solutions to .NET4 these problems started...

Comment: clean checkout builds in VS, does not build in msbuild

Comment: Ok, I didn't read anything about the change to .net 4.0 in your question. Have you changed the 4.0 framework in you test project too?

Comment: All projects are targeted for .NET 4

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the issue that building from VS is not always the same as simply using msbuild. What helped me then is to create a log of the msbuild run (/fl switch) and check the log and trace down the build steps and try to find the problematic task.

Comment: Ran it through the log as you suggested, and added the results to the original post. see edit 4

Comment: Usually one needs the whole log to see if there are any problems. Anyway can you make an example solution to show this problem ? (since i tried to reproduce this and did not succeed)

Comment: if I find the time for it I'll try

Answer (score 0):

I inspect the dll properties missed and I see that the assembly name have the same name of the default namespace.
Then I change the assembly name to a different one and I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same issue.

I really doubt why MSBuild throws missing assembly reference when ever we run the solution file through MSBuild and Jenkins but it works like a charm in the Visual Studio, After fighting for two days I found a conclusion for this.

I wrote a batch script to run the Solution file first through Visual Studio and then ran the Solution file. It is not working fine.

All you need to do is to call the batch script and then run the MSBuild/Jenkins.

Batch script :

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
devenv "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TFS\Product\Soluttion.sln" /Rebuild

devenv: To run the Visual Studio in Command line.

Note: you really need Visual Studio if your running MSBuild/Jenkins in the server.

Mail me for any issues regarding this..........

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error message when I built a solution with MSBuild in Release mode, even though Debug mode worked fine and both worked in Visual Studio. Turned out in the solution settings the project was not configured to be built for "Release|Mixed Platforms" or "Release|Any CPU".

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using AnyCPU and Prefer-32 bit, it still didn't work. Also tried with AnyCPU without checking Prefer-32 bit but nothing worked. I was having this issue when Deploying my code using the Bamboo. I made sure my **packages are all checked in to the code**(as my nuget restore in bamboo have an issue) and make sure my dll references in the project are looking at the packages in their paths. I checked in my packages by removing the **/packages** from the .gitignore file. Also, updated my packages.config file in the project to mention the package and the version to use. 
For Ex: 
Also, made sure the Agent on which the Deployment task is running, it has the needed .NET framework version. With the above all changes, I could resolve this reference issue.

Answer (score 0):

My project configuration file "**csproj**" had two <ItemGroup> sections with <ProjectReference>s

This error has gone when I merged these <ItemGroup> sections.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Visual Studio 2019 project.

The issue was solved by migrating project references from **packages.config** to **PackageReference**.

From the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#migration-steps):

> 1. Open a solution containing project using `packages.config`.
> 2. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the **References** node or the `packages.config` file and select **Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...**.
>
> [...]

> **Note**
>
> Before migration begins, Visual Studio creates a backup of the project to allow you to roll back to packages.config if necessary.

Comment: I started having this problem *after* migrating to PackageReference. Just saying... :(